# Meaning of output of mount

Tags: mount

```
$ mount
/dev/sda3 on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro,commit=0)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
none on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (rw)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880)
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
none on /run/user type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=104857600,mode=0755)
none on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw)
/dev/sda4 on /home type ext4 (rw,commit=0)
binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
systemd on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,none,name=systemd)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/1000/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=t)
```

The format of the output of mount is a sequence of lines, where each line has the format "A on B type C".

Do I understand correctly that

- B is the mount point
- C is the file system type. Examples of C are `ext4`, `proc`, `sysfs`, `tmpfs`, `fusectl`, `debugfs`, `securityfs`, `devtmpfs`, `devpts`, `pstore`, `binfmt_misc`, `cgroup`, `fuse.gvfsd-fuse`.
- what is A? Examples of A are `/dev/sda3`, `proc`, `sysfs`, `none`, `udev`, `devpts`, `tmpfs`, `binfmt_misc`, `systemd`, `gvfsd-fuse`.

Comment: The `A` is a device node/file mounted at mount point.

Comment: do you mean `proc` and `udev` are device files?

Comment: I mean that generic file systems are having device/file backing the mounted fs. Artificial file systems like procfs or tmpfs does not.

Answer (score 1):

The output of the `mount` command with no arguments is what the *input* of `mount` was when the filesystem was mounted (i.e., what its arguments were, what it detected the filesystem to be, and/or what was configured in `/etc/fstab`).

The `mount` command expects at least three bits of information: the *thing* to mount, the *place* to mount it on, and the *type* of the filesystem that is being mounted. The type is specified with the `-t` option to mount, but can often be autodetected, or can be specified in `fstab`. For filesystems that represent data on an actual device (such as ext4, xfs, or VFAT), the *thing* to mount is the device node of the device being mounted. For virtual filesystems such as procfs or sysfs, the concept of a thing to be mounted is meaningless (they simply expose some data from the kernel to userspace, there is no device or some such), but `mount` still requires the information. In theory, you can specify anything you want as the *thing* for such filesystems (try it: `mkdir /tmp/sys; mount -t sysfs weirdthingthatismounted /tmp/sys; mount`), but conventionally a name that describes the filesystem being mounted is used instead (e.g., the name of the filesystem, or the mountpoint with any slashes removed)

The `mount` command furthermore also takes options that may change the behavior of the filesystem (e.g., a `nodev` mount option), and it passes all that information on to the kernel, which connects the filesystem to the mount point, and also exposes the data that it was given in `/proc/mtab`. When you later run `mount` with no arguments, it simply outputs the data from that file.

The format is then (to use the terms from my previous paragraphs):

```
*thing* on *place* type *type* (*options*)
```

Answer (score 0):

A could be the physical device, as you see it in 'fdisk -l' or could be a node/file in special cases.